# persisting a list of objects in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have a class called Device.class and i want to have a field that is  a list of CommentObj.class . the problem is that this field is not persisted in database (I'm using Ebean). how is it possible to do so?

```
@Entity
public class Device extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;

@Constraints.MaxLength(50)
@Constraints.Required
public String serialNo;

...

public List<CommentObj> comments = new ArrayList<CommentObj>();
```

and

```
public class CommentObj extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;


@Constraints.MaxLength(50)
public String author;

@Constraints.MaxLength(500)
@Constraints.Required
public String content;

@Constraints.Required
public Date date;

public static Finder<Long, CommentObj> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, CommentObj.class);

public CommentObj(String author, String content){
    this.author = author;
    this.content = content;
    date = new Date();
}

}
```

here is the structure of Device in database (according to 1.sql). there is no sign of comments field

```
create table device (
  id                        bigint not null,
  serial_no                 varchar(255),
  invent_no                 varchar(255),
  name                      varchar(255),
  device_type_id            bigint,
  description               varchar(2000),
  cal_date                  timestamp,
  cal_duration_in_months    integer,
  setup_id                  bigint,
  manufacturer_id           bigint,
  constraint pk_device primary key (id))
;
```

Comment: If you have a one to many relation between Device and CommentObj, then you should only have a `device_id` column in your CommentObj table. When you ask for the comments list, basically Ebean will load the rows in CommentObj that match that foreign key...

Comment: @salem, in this case i have to annotate CommentObj with Entity and add a Device field to it. but i don't actually need to get the device from a commentObj. it is a one way relation.  is there any other solution? a solution without having the device_id in my commentObj ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do have a `device_id` in your comment_obj table, you can have a unidirectional OneToMany mapping by adding the following annotations to your `Device.class`' `comments` field:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "device_id")
public List<CommentObj> comments = new ArrayList<CommentObj>();
```